# Pycharm: How to run a single pytest instead of all?

Tags: pycharm, pytest

I use pytest in PyCharm (2022.3).

I want to run a single test function or a single test file only.

#### Project Structure and Tests

My Project structure looks like this:

```
project
  -src
  -tests
    -test_func_a.py
    -test_func_b.py
```

Where both test files contain multiple functions of the standard pytest form like:

```
def test_func_a_smth():
    assert x == y
```

#### Issue

When I try to run `test_func_a` the following configuration is created:
[image: PyCharm Dialog: Run Configuration for pytest]

But PyCharm runs all test files completely.

#### What I tried to solve it

What I have done so far:

- Checked that the content root is set to `project` and that `tests` is marked as "Tests Sources Root".
- Changed working directory to project.
- Updated pytest over anaconda.
- Set pytest as default test runner in the settings (Tools -> Python Integrated Tools)

None of these helped.

How can I execute a single test file only?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are having trouble executing an individual file.  Pycharm likes to re-run the last thing run, so perhaps you ran all tests and it wants to keep doing that.  Try these:

1. right click on the file name for the individual test cases you want to run in the project directory and select "run tests in ..." from there
2. Open the individual file with the tests and hit ctrl-shift-r from within the file (run this file)
3. You should also see small green arrows next to individual tests within the file, you can select those individually.

after you have run a couple different things, the "pull down" menu next to the run option in the header bar will have the different things you've done if you care to repeat.  I usually just use ctrl-shift-r from wherever I'm at.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried all of them and had the same result. To be sure that no old tests interfered I also terminated all tests before trying these steps. It does create new run configurations when I delete them first, but still ends up running all tests.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, working directory should be the same as project directory.

I had the same issue. What helpful for me is fixing pytest.ini_options. I changed this one:

```
addopts = " -s --cov=./ --cov-report term-missing tests/ -v"
```

to this:

```
addopts = "-s -v --cov=./ --cov-report term-missing"
```

After this everything works fine.